# TSQL copy table data to another table with custom values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables with identical columns expect one which is userId. I want to copy all the data from the first table into the second one and add custom userId to the column that is missing. Thus far without success.

The query is shown below. Insert Quality, Quantity, Supplier and UserId (which doesn't exist in the table im getting data)

```
`DECLARE @UserId int = 5611; -- add this to all the data from dbo.GasStation

INSERT INTO dbo.NewGasStation (Quality, Quantity, Supplier, UserId)
SELECT * FROM dbo.GasStation -- UserId doesn't exist in this table
-- Add somehow @UserId to all the data i'm getting from GasStation in order to satisfy the column UserId in the NewGasStation`
```

All the data i'm getting from dbo.GasStation to be inserted to dbo.NewGasStation adding this custom UserId to all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `*` list the columns in your `SELECT` explicitly and add the variable to that list.

```
DECLARE @userid integer = 5611;

INSERT INTO dbo.newgasstation
           (quality,
            quantity,
            supplier,
            userid)
           SELECT quality,
                  quantity,
                  supplier,
                  @userid
                  FROM dbo.gasstation;
```

Comment: Doesn't work because @userId doesn't exist in the dbo.GasStation

Comment: @S.Minchev: Yes it does. You can add as many constant expressions as you want they don't need to exist in the table, they even cannot exist there. Just try it.

Comment: Well tell that to the sql management studio "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'Go41_db.dbo.NewGasStation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @stickybit . . . Wow.  Exactly the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You also don't need to discriminate the columns if you just want to copy them all. Just use the `*`.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @UserId integer = 5611;

INSERT INTO [Target]
SELECT *, @UserId FROM [Source]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@UserId` to the `SELECT` list:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewGasStation (Quality, Quantity, Supplier, UserId)
    SELECT Quality, Quantity, Supplier, @UserId
    FROM dbo.GasStation ;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you cant add @UserId at the end of this SELECT because it doesn't exist in the dbo.GasStation

Comment: @S.Minchev . . . Huh?  It is a constant.  Of course you can include it in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewGasStation (Quality, Quantity, Supplier, UserId)
SELECT Quality, Quantity, Supplier, '5611' FROM dbo.GasStation
```

should do the trick (assuming column names are the same for both tables)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the NewGasStation table does not exsist when running this

```
Select Quality, Quantity, Supplier,5611 as UserId
into NewGasStation
from GasStation
```

Comment: Well the problem here is there is already some data added so I can't do that :)